# Is there a function in google.colab module to close the runtime

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory

Sometimes when I give run in google.colab I cant stay infront of the computer to manually disconnect from the server when the run is complete and the connection stays on even when my run is complete occupying the node for no reason.

Is there a function in google.colab so that say I can insert the function to close the connection after some epochs? I am looking for something like colab.disconnect() etc...

Comment: https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/2568

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import sys
sys.exit()
```

This will end the runtime, freeing up the GPU.

EDIT: Apparently my last answer doesn't work any more.
The thing to do now is `!kill -9 -1`.

Comment: When I do this it remains connected but gives the message

An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:2890: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1).
Just saying quit or exit does not help neither

Comment: Huh, I swear that used to work. Okay, there's another thing you can do that will absolutely end the runtime. `!kill -9 -1`. It will still say you're connected, but the entire VM has actually stopped. You should be safe to leave then.

Comment: It only restarts the runtime, does not stop it.

Answer (score 9):

Since September 2022, it is now possible. From [@GoogleColab twitter](https://twitter.com/googlecolab/status/1569389018311426051?lang=en):

You can now terminate Colab sessions programmatically with the following code:

```
from google.colab import runtime
runtime.unassign()
```

The new `unassign()` function marks the currently connected runtime for deletion and disconnects any notebook sessions.

Answer (score 6):

`quit()` and `exit()` are not executed in google colab (18 Aug 2019). Just type the following:

```
!kill -9 -1
```

Comment: I'm a colab newbie (so may be confused) but then I tried `!kill -9 -1` it seemed to treat it like an accidental disconnect, and began trying to reconnect, which it did in 10-20 seconds. (As of 2021-11-19, two years after the answer by @Farzad Amirjavid

Comment: This resets the installed pip packages too