# How can I disconnect the google colab runtime from within a cell?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I often start a training run before going to bed and I'd like to release the runtime from within the last cell of my notebook. How can I do this?

My motivation is simply to save the extra 90 minutes of usage before the idle timeout kills the runtime anyway, so I accumulate fewer GPU hours and stay at a higher priority... (Maybe that's a pointless goal...)

Comment: Check following question: [Is there a function in google.colab module to close the runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50541851/is-there-a-function-in-google-colab-module-to-close-the-runtime)

Comment: Thanks! (The answer from there is `!kill -9 -1`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To post the answer mentioned in the comments above (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50541851/is-there-a-function-in-google-colab-module-to-close-the-runtime)):

Run `!kill -9 -1` from within a cell.

Answer (score 18):

kill won't delete the runtime. And you'll still be charged for it. To disconnect and delete use:

```
from google.colab import runtime
runtime.unassign()
```

Source (and also checked): https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleColab/comments/xtj2be/dear_googlecolab_boss_i_want/

Comment: I don't understand why this is not the accepted answer. The person who asked the question wants to accumulate less GPU hours and simply `!kill -9 -1` won't do it. This answer, however, does.