# How to stop Google Colab runtime without it automatically restarting

Tags: python, linux, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I want to stop a [Google Colab](https://colab.to) notebook programmatically when the thing I want to do has ended, I thought of putting a line at the end that would stop it from running. I have tried these, but none work. They all restart instead of shutting down or then just give an error.

**I got these from here:**

- [Is there a function in google.colab module to close the runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50541851/is-there-a-function-in-google-colab-module-to-close-the-runtime/)
- https://newbedev.com/google-colab-how-to-restart-runtime-using-python-code-or-command-line-interface

```
import os
os.kill(os.getpid(), 9)
```

```
import sys
sys.exit()
```

```
exit()
```

```
quit()
```

```
!kill -9 -1
```

There is a shortcut for ending all runtimes, (It's undefined by default by I added it as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>), so maybe I could write a program that would virtually type those keys. But it opens a popup before shutting down and I may not be there to confirm it.

**How can I do this? Thanks!**

Comment: https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/2568

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now (since September 12th, 2022) you can do this:

```
from google.colab import runtime
runtime.unassign()
```

It was announced in this GitHub issue: https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/2568. Thanks @HappyFace for commenting this link.